# Jmeter nginx server performance test

Tags: performance, server, jmeter

I need to check the nginx server performance using jmeter to perform the load testing,I had searched and found that jmeter support tomcat server ,kindly help me with any open source pulg in to check the server performance

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support of collecting nginx server health metrics (like Tomcat) in JMeter, however you can consider using the relevant plugin.

You will need:

- [PerfMon Server Agent](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) - on nginx server side
- [PerfMon Metric Collector](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) - on JMeter side (comes with [JMeter Plugins Standard Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/StandardSet/))

Check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) guide for detailed installation, configuration and usage instructions.